# extjs localstorage paging

Tags: extjs, local-storage

I have a very basic app in extjs with a localstorage type proxy. Problem is that I can't use paging to reduce my results in the grid. It always loads all records no matter what limit i set:

```
var itemsPerPage = 1;
var cProxyStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: "cProxyModel",
    autoLoad: {start: 0, limit: itemsPerPage},
        autoSync: true,
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    }
});
```

Any idea how to make paging work on this type of proxy?

Comment: do u check the server recieve the correct params?

Comment: it's a localStorage proxy. there's no server, just the browser storing data

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a second storage reference and populate it with the paging logic you need then fill the store with the proper storage reference.

The paging logic is usually done in the server side, just because the server is not in use in your case does not mean you can skip the necessary logic ( That is, you will have to find a place to do it since the store will not do it for you, the store does have control over the data being handed to it)